# Strings.xml or String ressource in Eclipse Java (not Android)

Tags: java, xml, string, eclipse

I have to research, if a normally Java-Project have the privilege to use a String.xml like a Android-Project, for store all the String variables. I haven't found anything on internet. When I search for String ressources, I get information only for Android.

I think it makes easier to translate the String-Values in each other languages.

When it is not possible: is there any other way to define Strings in Eclipse, to translate it easy? I wouldn't like use hardcoded strings. (Sorry for my english!)

Comment: you can use property files.

Comment: @mustafacil thank you now I can keep going on

Answer (score 1):

Instead of xml file, you can use properties files:
[Look here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/)

Comment: thank you! I have found this for internalization with property-files : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/steps.html